# VIM - Regex - Multi-Line Search Query for changes in field value

Tags: regex, vim, replace, sed, grep

I have a massive log file that includes an example of a device driver failing. The driver is supposed to provide data from a buffer, which the client application reads. The driver logs the amount of data in the buffer before and after the read, and transfers data to the client in 512 byte chunks. There is a lot of junk data randomly scattered across multiple lines in the log file. Below is a brief example or a normal working case.

```
Before Transfer 1: Available 512 bytes
... junk data
After Transfer 1: Available 0 bytes
... junk data
Before Transfer 2: Available 512 bytes
... junk data
After Transfer 2: Available 0 bytes
```

In the error case, it looks like so (the Transfer number is just from a specific example; the issue doesn't always occur on transfer #35):

```
Before Transfer 34: Available 512 bytes
... junk data
After Transfer 34: Available 0 bytes
... junk data
Before Transfer 35: Available 512 bytes
... junk data
After Transfer 35: Available 512 bytes
```

So, I'm trying to match a multi-line query where a single transfer reports the same amount "available" in the "Before" and "After" logging statements.

I've tried this: `:%s/Before Transfer.* 512 bytes\._*After Transfer.* 512 bytes`, and it helps find **some** of the issues, but the amount might be 1024, or 256, or some multiple of 256 bytes in the "Before" and "After" logging statements.

Additionally, this query seems to highlight more than half of the file buffer in VIM. I'm assuming this is because it finds matching queries within other queries (ie: nested results) because I haven't provided it with a way to only match with **corresponding** "Before"/"After" instance numbers in the log file.

I would like to set up a regex that goes through each **matching** "Before" and "After" log line, and see if the data value (number of bytes) is the same both "Before" and "After". If both of these criteria are met, it is a "match" as far as the regex search query is concern. The desired output, in the case of a file I more-or-less manually parsed, was like so:

```
Before Transfer 35: Available 512 bytes
After Transfer 35: Available 512 bytes
Before Transfer 105: Available 256 bytes
After Transfer 105: Available 256 bytes
Before Transfer 220: Available 512 bytes
After Transfer 220: Available 512 bytes
Before Transfer 250: Available 2048 bytes
After Transfer 250: Available 2048 bytes
```

How do I go about creating such a query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vim, you could use following steps

```
v/\v^(before|after) transfer/d
%norm J
v/\vbefore transfer.{-}(\d+ bytes).{-}\1/d
```

where

**v/\v^(before|after) transfer/d**
Delete every line not starting with *before* or *after transfer*

**%norm J**
Join all remaing lines. Note that this assumes that each before matches up with an after. If it doesn't, you'll have to remove the orphan lines *(using a regex :))*

**v/\vbefore transfer.{-}(\d+ bytes).{-}\1/d**
Delete every line not containing the *same* number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't need to be in vim and all you want are the numbers of the failed transfers and the buffer sizes then this will work:

```
awk '/^Before Transfer/{s[$3]=$5; next} /^After Transfer/&&(s[$3] == $5) {print "Transfer "$3" failed with "$5" available."; delete s[$3]; next}'
```

You can format the output or save the input lines or do whatever else you want on top of that but that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/Before Transfer/ h
        /After Transfer/ { x
           G
           /\(Available  *[0-9]* \).*\1/ s/\n/& /p
           }' YourFile
```

Just added a space before After for better presentation and separation